# Powershell free disk space for drives without drive letter

Tags: powershell, diskspace

I am working on a power shell script based on http://www.powershellneedfulthings.com/?p=36 to check the disk space for volumes that do not have a driver letter assigned.

The script works pretty well, but I'd like to filter that only drives are shown that have less than 10% free disk space. I'm running into troubles using the where-object filter with hash tables.

```
# calculations for displaying disk size information
$TotalGB = @{Name="Capacity(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.Capacity/ 1GB),2)}}
$FreeGB = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.FreeSpace / 1GB),2)}}
$FreePerc = @{Name="Free(%)";expression={[math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0)}}

# array declarations
$volumes = @()

# import server names to check
$servers = (Get-Content .\servers.txt)

# check disk space for volumes without drive letter
foreach ($server in $servers){
   $volumes += Get-WmiObject -computer $server win32_volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -eq $null -and $_.Label -ne "System Reserved"}
}
$volumes | Select SystemName, Label, $TotalGB, $FreeGB, $FreePerc | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

What I tried is:

```
Where-Object {$FreePerc -le 10}
```

The current output is:

```
SystemName Label        Capacity(GB) FreeSpace(GB) Free(%)
---------- -----        ------------ ------------- ----
SERVER01   X:\data\             9.97          0.89   9
SERVER01   X:\log\              9.97          1.20   12
SERVER01   X:\info\             9.97          3.49   35
```

I'd like to only show the volumes that have less than 10% free disk space. So in this case, only the first entry should be shown.

Thanks!

Comment: @arco444 thanks, but this does not seem to have any effect either

Comment: Do you have some sample output then so we can see what we need to filter on? Also you put the `Where-Object {$FreePerc -le 10}` before the `Format-table` correct

Comment: @Matt i have added the output to the code above. when i add the `Where-Object {$FreePerc -le 10}` before the `Format-table` I will get an error: `Bad argument to operator '-le': Could not compare "System.Collections.Hashtable" to "10". Error: "Cannot convert the "10" value of type "System.Int32" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".".`

Comment: I dont think it like the where clause with the HashTable property `$FreePerc`. 'Free(%)' could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the where clause variable `$FreePerc` is the issue. Arco had the right idea.

```
$volumes | Select SystemName, Label, $TotalGB, $FreeGB, $FreePerc | Where-Object {$_.'Free(%)' -le 10}  | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I put the property in single quotes because i think PowerShell would try to evaluate `(%)` otherwise. Also to make Arco's solution work it might just be easier to call the `Name` propery of `$FreePerc`. That way you only have to update one location

```
$volumes | Select SystemName, Label, $TotalGB, $FreeGB, $FreePerc | Where-Object {$_.($FreePerc.Name) -le 10}  | Format-Table -AutoSize
```